# Iterate Row Selection takes too much of the model into ModelBuilder loop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I am a little stuck with a relatively simple model.

What I want:

1) Create a table "results".

2) Loop over "Points".

3) Do some buffer and counting

4) Put the results (OBJECTID and count) into "results" via "addRecord"

5) Goto 2

What it does:
1) -> 2) -> 3) -> 4) and then it creates "results" again which somehow empties results.

Any hints ?

addRecord looks like this:

```py
   import arcpy

   infile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
   IDFieldValue = long(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))
   CountFieldValue = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

   rows = arcpy.InsertCursor(infile)

   row = rows.newRow()
   row.setValue("OID", IDFieldValue)
   row.setValue("count", CountFieldValue)
   rows.insertRow(row)

   del row
   del rows
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to separate your model into two models. As you have it now, the results table gets created with every iteration. Step 1 needs to be in separate model that calls a sub model, which performs the rest of the steps. Refer to this [help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Integrating_a_model_within_a_model/002w0000007p000000/) on how to set up nested models.

Comment: Thanx - couldn't really make it work - problems with preconditions. Ended up coding it in python :) Let me know if someone wants to see the code.